# How to remove and re-add a scrollable NSTextView to a view?

Tags: swift, nsscrollview, undo-redo

I have a scrollable `NSTextView` which holds unique text linked to `NSTableView` cells. The undo and redo functions were getting confused when I select different `NSTableView` cells and update the `NSTextView` to hold its new `NSAttributedString` value so I thought I would try to remove the scroll view and re-add it every time I want to update it to hopefully reset the undo/redo chain.

This is my code so far:

```
var scrollView: NSScrollView = {
    let scroll = NSTextView.scrollableTextView()
    scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scroll
}()
var textView: NSTextView = {
    let view = NSTextView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

func updateView() { // my function to call when a new tableview cell is selected
    self.scrollView.removeFromSuperview()

    textView = scrollView.documentView as! NSTextView
    self.addSubView(scrollView)
    self.setUpConstraints() // my function containing layout constraints
}
```

but there is just blank space. Here is my `setUpConstraints()` function:

```
func setUpConstraints() { // I have other constraints in my program which relate to each other. All working.
    let scrollViewConstraints = [
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 15),
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -14),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
    ]
    let allConstraints = [
        scrollViewConstraints
    ]
    for constraints in allConstraints {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```

I have other views such as `NSTextField`s which I am handling in the exact same way which all work perfectly fine. The problem is that I can put `self.addSubView(scrollView)` in `viewDidMoveToSuperview` just fine but when I put it in my `updateView` function, it doesn't work. (fyi: updateView is a delegate function for my table view)
I am open to other solutions to my problem with undo/redo as well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the code of `setUpConstraints` please. If you want help solving the undo issue then ask a new question.

Comment: I didn't add the `setUpConstraints()` code because it works just fine and has a lot of constraints in it, but I will edit to include the function and change the constraints to not reference other subviews not mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried "Capture View Hierarchy"? Where are the scroll view and the text view?

Comment: I have now, wow that is a cool xCode feature that I did not know about! the scrollable text view is nowhere to be found. It loads fine in `viewDidMoveToSuperview` with exact same set up but when I try to add and constrain it from my `updateView` function it just doesn't.

Comment: I don't think removing and adding views is a solution to undo problems but if you still want to try this then post a [mre] please.